# How to set global configuration of Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Gillardo bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker in my application and i wanted to override some default setting(wanted to remove buttonBar).For that i have used the following code which does not solve my problem (code get from library documentation [uiDatetimePickerConfig Documentation](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker#uidatetimepickerconfig)). I have also searched but didn't find any help.

**Note:Library is working fine only i wanted to remove buttonBar**

[image: buttoBar]

Any suggestion.

Here html where shown datetimepicker

```
<p class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-datetime ng-dirty ng-touched ng-not-empty"
                                               datetime-picker="HH:mm" ng-model="range.endTime"
                                               is-open="range.dEndTime" enable-date="false" 
                                               readonly>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.openCalendar($event,range,2)"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></button>
                                        </span>

                                    </p>
```

[Library](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker#uidatetimepickerconfig)

**Library injected**

```
var myAdminApp = new FHCommon.Module("FHAdminApp", ["daterangepicker", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker"]); //some injection have removed where are not relevant
```

**Config**

```
 myAdminApp.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    myAdminApp.constant('uiDatetimePickerConfig',
    {
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
        defaultTime: '00:00:00',
        html5Types: {
            date: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'datetime-local': 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sss',
            'month': 'yyyy-MM'
        },
        initialPicker: 'date',
        reOpenDefault: false,
        enableDate: true,
        enableTime: true,
        //buttonBar: {
        //    show: true,
        //    now: {
        //        show: true,
        //        text: 'Now'
        //    },
        //    date: {
        //        show: true,
        //        text: 'Date'
        //    },
        //    time: {
        //        show: true,
        //        text: 'Time'
        //    },
        //    close: {
        //        show: true,
        //        text: 'Close'
        //    }
        //},
        closeOnDateSelection: true,
        closeOnTimeNow: true,
        appendToBody: false,
        altInputFormats: [],
        ngModelOptions: {},
        saveAs: false,
        readAs: false,
    });

//other code

    }
```

Comment: So i guess you tried set the `show` parameters to `false` before comment everything?

Comment: @VassilisPits i have found the solution and explain in the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time spend just found a way but this is not a globall . just added this line `button-bar="{{false}}"` in input element.

**Code**

```
<p class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-datetime ng-dirty ng-touched ng-not-empty"
                                               datetime-picker="HH:mm" ng-model="range.endTime"
                                               is-open="range.dEndTime" enable-date="false" 
                                               button-bar="{{false}}" readonly>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.openCalendar($event,range,2)"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></button>
                                        </span>

                                    </p>
```

[image: After problem solved]